# Monitor User actions in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am a beginner in android programming and keen to evolve in the same.
I want to create a app that can monitor user actions in terms of time, for example 'how much time they spent on calling?' or 'how much time they spent on whats app?' or 'How much time were their phone idle(not using any app at all)?' and store this into a file or database. 
How can I do so?
Would it be preferable to create a service that runs in the background? or 
Is there a easier way to log user actions?
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The time spend when the user is on the app can be done directly. But if we were to calculate the time the phone is idle I think we need to implement a service. You can start the timer in oncreate in the application class, and end it when the last activity is onPause or onStop. Store the time in shared preferences so it is persistent. I hope I have been helpful

Comment: Thank You for the reply. But my question is with respect to different apps installed on the users phone (not specific to the app I developed). It is my fault I didn't specify clearly in the question, but now have corrected it. Sorry and Thank You again